# AWS Appmesh ECS virtual Node and Service Discovery, how to set the DNS, is it automatically created? if not how to set it up

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-ecs, aws-app-mesh

I am fairly new to AWS ECS App Mesh, so please excuse if i am asking something naive,

I am trying to create the App mesh when doing the creation of the virtual node, it is asking the service discovery method, i chose DNS there and now i need to provide the hostname in there

as per my understanding this hostname should be the internal DNS setup because the service to service communication it should not go to route53, so how to get the DNS here, am i missing some step, Do i need to create the DNS or there is an inbuilt one.

After some search found that the virtual node name is the default hostname in the local domain, but what is the local domain, if i do nslookup for the default domain it says not found

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/app-mesh/latest/userguide/virtual_nodes.html

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be whatever the internal DNS name of  the service is that you are trying to point to. If you don't have a DNS name yet, you probably need to add a Route53 [Private Hosted Zone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html) to the VPC, and configure the DNS name in that private hosted zone.

> as per my understanding this hostname should be the internal DNS setup because the service to service communication it should not go to route53

That's not entirely correct. As per the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/app-mesh/latest/userguide/virtual_nodes.html), App Mesh will use your VPC's DNS resolution. As per the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html), the VPC's DNS resolution uses an internal Route53 DNS server, and you can add custom DNS names to that by attaching a Route53 Private Hosted Zone to the VPC.